# How many number greater than $1000$ can be formed by using the digits $1,1,2,3,4,0$ taken four at a time?

Tags: combinatorics

How many number greater than $1000$ can be formed by using the digits $1,1,2,3,4,0$ taken four at a time?

I am getting $186$ numbers as my answer.

**My solution:**

1st case all 4 different digits (5 cases) .. this has 2 sub cases: 0 included (4 cases) and 0 not included (1 case) .... For 0 included total numbers $= (4!-3!)4$ and 0 not included $(4!) \cdot 1$.

Next case will be 2 alike digits and 2 different digits (6 cases) ..it's sub cases are 0 included (3 cases) and 0 not included (3 cases) ... Total Numbers for 0 included $(4!/2! -3!/2!)3$ and for 0 not included $(4!/2!)3$.

Adding up all the cases, I am getting $186$.

Comment: Share with us how you arrived at the number $186$ so we can point out what specifically you did wrong.  It is arguably more important to see mistakes and learn from them than it is to see a correct solution.

Comment: 1st case all 4 different digits (5cases) .. this has 2 sub case 0 included (4cases) and 0 not included (1 case) .... For 0 included  total numbers = (4!-3!)4 and 0 not included (4!)*1

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question itself (by clicking on the Edit button at the bottom of your post) rather than placing it in the comments, where it might be missed.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Next case will be 2 alike digits and 2 different digits (6 cases) ..it's sub cases is 0 include (3 cases) and 0 not include (3 cases) ... Total Numbers for 0 included (4!/2! -3!/2! )3 and for 0 not included (4!/2!)3

Comment: When I add your numbers, I obtain $159$ rather than $186$ since $(4! - 3!) \cdot 4 = (24 - 6) \cdot 4 = 18 \cdot 4 = 72$, $4! = 24$, $(\frac{4!}{2!} - \frac{3!}{2!}) \cdot 3 = (\frac{24}{2} - \frac{3}{2}) \cdot 3 = (12 - 3) \cdot 3 = 9 \cdot 3 = 27$, and $\frac{4!}{2!} \cdot 3 = \frac{24}{2} \cdot 3 = 12 \cdot 3 = 36$.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to your attempt, it appears correct however you seem to have made an arithmetic mistake.  Your answer of $(4!-3!)\cdot 4 + (4!)\cdot 1 + (4!/2!-3!/2!)\cdot 3 + (4!/2!)\cdot 3$ [should have totaled $159$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4*%284%21-3%21%29%2B4%21+%2B+%284%21%2F2%21-3%21%2F2%21%29*3+%2B+%284%21%2F2%21%29*3) and not $186$.

I do find it a bit cumbersome having broken into the cases you selected however.

---

For an alternate, perhaps cleaner approach, I recommend breaking into three cases:

- Two $1$'s are used and one of them is the leading digit.
- Two $1$'s are used and neither is the leading digit.
- One or fewer $1$'s are used

For the first case: two $1$'s are used and one of them is the leading digit, this is just the question of where the second $1$ goes, and what digits fill the remaining two empty positions.  This gives a total of $3\times 4\times 3$ outcomes in this case

For the second case: two $1$'s are used but neither is the leading digit.  First pick the positions of the $1$'s (*can be done in $3$ ways*).  Then, pick a non-zero number for the leading digit, and then pick any remaining number for the final position.  This gives a total of $3\times 3\times 3$ outcomes in this case.

Finally, for the third case: ignore that there are two $1$'s in the list of available digits.  pick a nonzero number for the leading, pick any other for the second digit, pick any other for the third, and any for the fourth.  This gives a total of $4\times 4\times 3\times 2$ outcomes for this case.

This gives a final total of:

$$3\times 4\times 3 + 3\times 3\times 3 + 4\times 4\times 3\times 2 = 159$$